# PHP Ecommerce API - Payment process

Tags: php, api, e-commerce, payment-gateway

I am developing an ecommerce API with all features of products, catalogs, orders etc... I am stucked in how to process with payment gateways like  ccavenue, payumoney... etc those payment gateways are redirecting to banks sites for authentication so I couldn't process this with API. Anyone please help me for making flow of payment process in E commerce API system ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: They all offer sandboxes (ie test environements), did you try asking these providers for a test environement ?

Comment: no... I asking how can we provide an API call for payment process to external users

Comment: I see, short answer is : nope, you can't blindly proxy these calls

Answer (score 4):

usually when the gateway redirect the browser to their website, you have to do the following:

**After user click checkout:**

- Create the order in pending status
- generate transaction ID or just use the order ID
- send the transaction ID / Order ID with request to the gateway

**after gateway finish and redirect the browser to your site**

- get the **status** [success / fail]
- get the **transaction ID / Order ID**

*[gateway must return the transaction Id which
   you supply it]*

- update the order / transaction using the **ID** and **Status**

**Important**

some customer will just close the gateway page without continue the process,, 
so you will get a lot of pending orders after couple days,, also the stock will be decreased.

to solve this issue you should run cron job each `1 hour for example` .. it will cancel any pending orders which are created from more than 10 minutes and it will restock the products

**Another Solution:**

some gateways ask you to give them confirm URL .. and after the transaction is done .. they send the results to your confirm URL ,, so you have to develop API in your site to process this confirmation response,, in this case even if the user has problem in his browser after finish the transaction and he could not redirect back to your site .. he will get success order

**EDIT**

okay then you have three sides in the transaction life cycle

1- customer website : we will call it **caller**

2- your API provider: will call it **API**

3- finally the **gateway**

so put in your mind this process can not be done successfully without save some information in API side

the process will go like the following

- caller will create order in pending status
- caller will send transaction info to your API, this information must have the **return URL + the transaction ID**
- API will save the received information in its DB and generate another request to the gateway, this request must have the **return URL + the transaction Id**
- after gateway finish, it will redirect to your API,, your API will extract the results and return it to Caller return URL
- caller will receive the response, extract the results, update the order

**Important:**

if you would like to keep the process between the caller and gateway

**Case A:**

usually gateway redirect the user by return html form + JS script which will submit the form when this html is rendered ..

so in this case ..do not print the html repose and just return it to caller ,, let him print it .. so in this case redirection will happen between caller and gateway

**Case B:**

- let your API prepare the request and the endpoint then return this data to caller
- let caller send this request to gateway
- gateway will return the response to caller
- caller will send the response to API to extract the results
- API will return the caller the final results
- caller will update order

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You another solution I like it... you added some extra info what I expected to ask with next question... But here one issue is.. We can't request to payment gateway from API system... we have redirect from user server (who uses our API) and payment gateway is returning data to user server only... API system won't get direct notification from payment gateway.. RIght ? so is there any way to overcome from this issue... I hope you understood it... Is it  ?

Comment: hummm let me post another answer for you

Answer (score 0):

All Payment gateways have a field to pass your custom value/ order id. And they will return you back that value. Look into their documentation. Also look for notification fields.

Comment: HI Mickey, You may be talking about 2checkout process flow. But there are some payment gateways which is not giving return value until user has to authenticate with the bank's site.